# MongoDB speed query when searching by part of text

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have smallish size database with 2 million records of phone calls.

When I execute:

```js
db.getCollection('calls').find({  
    'IsIncoming':true, 'DateCreated' : { '$gte':ISODate('2010-12-02T02:26:22.478Z') }, 'CallerIdNum':"2545874578"
}).limit(100).count({})
```

it is supper fast and it takes 95ms. **Note that `IsIncoming`, `DateCreted` and `CallerIdNum` have indexes. Every time I search using those fields it is supper fast**

The moment I search for something containing part of a text it is very slow. For example this query now takes 25 seconds:

```js
db.getCollection('calls').find({  
    'IsIncoming':true, 'DateCreated' : { '$gte': ISODate('2010-12-02T02:26:22.478Z') }, 'CallerIdNum' : /2545874/
}).limit(100).count({})
```

I know the reason is because I am searching within `CallerIdNum`. If I where to know the full caller id in advance like on my first query then it will be fast.

### Question

I will like the last query to execute faster. I know it is probably impossible, and the only way of getting a great performance is by searching by the whole CallerIdNum. But maybe/hopefully I am wrong and someone can help me find a way of executing my last query faster.

Comment: you have a compound index in the first case right? just curiosity, you could get better performance using `^` and `$` but you probably know this.

Comment: @Minsky Good question I know just the basics about databases. I created the index with this query `db.calls.createIndex({CallerIdNum:1})`. How can I know if it is a compound index?

Comment: Your bottleneck is obviously the regex. But imagine the indexes the same than in a book. When mongo looks that index, it finds the value (the document id), but doesn't know the other fields! Then it has to go back from the index to the book (only know it can read quicker), and fetch the documents.

Comment: I could tell you how to build the compound index, but since it won't really help..; If you know the shape, maybe something changes, `/\d\d\d31562456\d/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are searching for a *substring* of a caller ID number `/2545874/`.  The is not sargable, and generally can't use an index.  Assuming you really want numbers which start with that prefix, then use this sargable version:

```
db.getCollection('calls').find({  
    'IsIncoming':true, 'DateCreated' : { '$gte': ISODate('2010-12-02T02:26:22.478Z') }, 'CallerIdNum' : /^2545874/
}).limit(100).count({})
```

You might also want to add a compound index on all three fields, though at least the version of the query I gave above can use an index involving the `CallerIdNum` field.

Comment: how do you back up the claim it can't use index? I don't think that's true.

Comment: If the caller Id field has a B tree index, then it can only use a prefix.

Comment: Works great thanks Tim. If I want to search for some text in between I guess that will be impossible correct?

Comment: @TonoNam Your current query is already logically doing that, it just isn't fast enough.  If you do a substring operation it might be faster.  And also, Mongo might have other types of indices besides B tree.

Comment: You already answered the question it is great. I am accepting it as soon as it lets me. I am just asking out of curiosity so I can learn more. I will search about other types of indeces then. Thanks again.

Comment: Correction @TonoNam: You can use an index if you create a Search Index in Atlas Search.

Comment: It will be much faster and yield more relevant results.